# Problem in edittext content

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a dynamic tabs. In each newly created tabs , i'm opening a file. I want to get the filename or file descriptor 
of the selected tab to do file operations on that corresponding file. For example If i want to delete the file, the file 
and the corresponding tab should be closed.
Please give suggestions...........

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be I miss something, but what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can set for each of your tab when you add dynamicall a Tag, which can be your filename or some unique identifier, or even a custom class that holds more data.

Lookup [setCurrentTabByTag](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html)

Comment: If i use these values in menus (delete, mail or etc). menu options are not working. I'l make it clear.
Now what i'm trying to do is :
Inside delete option of menu if i use

string tag=tabs.getCurrentTabByTab();
deleting the file which matches that tag.

it's not working.


I'm i following the right way.


Sorry for my english.

Comment: If something doesn't work with the delete, post a new questions.